# Error using dataset iterator as input to tensorflow model.fit()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

When I run this code:

```
x_train = tfds.load('ucf101', split='train', shuffle_files=True, batch_size = 64)

dim = lambda x: x['video'][:,30:40, ...]
x_train = x_train.map(dim)

model.compile(loss='mse',
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

checkpoint_path = "training_1/cp.ckpt"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)

# Create a callback that saves the model's weights
cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path,
                                                 save_weights_only=True,
                                                 verbose=1)

history = model.fit(x_train, x_train,
                    epochs=100,
                    verbose=1,
                    callbacks=[cp_callback])
```

I get the error :

`ValueError: You passed a dataset or dataset iterator (<MapDataset shapes: (None, None, 256, 256, 3), types: tf.uint8>) as input`x`to your model. In that case, you should not specify a target (`y`) argument, since the dataset or dataset iterator generates both input data and target data. Received: <MapDataset shapes: (None, None, 256, 256, 3), types: tf.uint8>`

It is an autoencoder, so x_train is provided as input and target intentionally. The dimensions of MapDataset are (batch, frame, height, width, rgb) and it doesn't contain any target data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model:

> If x is a dataset, generator or keras.utils.Sequence instance, y should not be specified (since targets will be obtained from the iterator/dataset).

If you want to use model.fit(), you will need to specify the target in your tf.data dataset, which could look something like:

```
x_train = tfds.load('ucf101', split='train', shuffle_files=True, batch_size = 64)

def parser(x):
  dim = x['video'][:,30:40, ...]
  return dim, dim

x_train = x_train.map(parser)

...

history = model.fit(x_train,
                    epochs=100,
                    verbose=1,
                    callbacks=[cp_callback])
```